# Get the column Value using Linq from dataset in c#

Tags: c#, linq

In the Linq after retrieving from the dataset how can i get the column data without using the for each statement?

```
 var query = from alias in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                        where alias.Field<string>("lanename") == ddlLaneController.SelectedItem.Text
                        select new
                        {
                            locname = alias["LocationName"],
                            locid = alias["locationid"]
                        };
```

txtStartLocation.Text = query.Select(a => a["LocationName"]).ToString();

Can i know how can i achieve this?

Thanks,
Vara Prasad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a single resulting row use `Single`:

```
txtStartLocation.Text = query.Single().locname;
```

Comment: Can't we get it from the select?

Comment: You could get it from the select if you write `var object = (your_query).SingleOrDefault();` and then write `txtStartLocation.Text = object.locname;`

Comment: Yes i got it by using the above one which is simplier

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use `First()`:

```
txtStartLocation.Text = query.First().locname.ToString();
```

Comment: Can't we get it from the select?

Comment: The select always returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, not a single value.